# Intentional QGIS crash

Tags: qgis-3

I want to crash QGIS 3.24 for debug purposes. Is there any function to call a crash intentionally? Except for searching the repository for [existing bugs](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20label%3A%22Crash%2FData%20Corruption%22) that cause the program to fail.

**UPDATE:**

I found in [PyQgis docs](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsSvgCache.html?highlight=crash#qgis.core.QgsSvgCache.getImageData) that QGIS can crash when calling the `getImageData` method of the `qgis.core.QgsSvgCache` class.

The description says:

> Warning
>
> The blocking parameter must NEVER be True from GUI based applications
> (like the main QGIS application) or crashes will result. Only for use
> in external scripts or QGIS server.

I started QGIS, opened the python console and wrote this (but it didn't crash):

```
svg_cache = qgis.core.QgsSvgCache()
svg_cache.getImageData(r'G:\!Download\410.svg', blocking=True)
```

Comment: This is an interesting question! I had a crash yesterday but I don't remember exactly why. If I find something reproducible, I shall let you know.

Comment: Have a look through the bug tracker if you see anything repeatable: https://github.com/qgis/qgis/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+crash

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389261/using-qobject-inside-thread-in-pyqgis