# Setting up thread with busy progress indicator or GIF in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, multithreading

As discussed in the comments of this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389261/using-qobject-inside-thread-in-pyqgis/429448#comment700700_429448) I have troubles understanding how to to set up a thread with a busy progress bar (or a GIF) within a plugin in QGIS.

I would like the progress bar to turn to a busy state when I run a function without freezing the plugin window (and QGIS) and I would like the time spent to run each tasks within my function to be displayed dynamically in the textBrowser.

Here is a plugin test sample:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *

from .resources import *
from .plugintest_dialog import plugintestDialog
from datetime import datetime
import os.path, os, shutil
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
import processing
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal


class MyTask(QgsTask):

    messaging = pyqtSignal(str)
    result = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, layer):
        super(MyTask, self).__init__()
        self.layer = layer

    def run(self):
        start = datetime.now()
        # buffer
        alg_params = {
            'DISSOLVE': True,
            'DISTANCE': 100,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
            'INPUT': self.layer,
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }

        self.buffer = processing.run('native:buffer', alg_params)

        if self.buffer['OUTPUT'].isValid:
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.buffer['OUTPUT'])

        time.sleep(4)

        end = datetime.now()

        buffer_info = "Layer Buffering..."
        buffer_title = '<center><h3><span style=\" color: #7eb346; font-weight:bold\">%s</span></h3></center>' % buffer_info
        self.dlg.textBrowser.append(buffer_title)
        self.dlg.textBrowser.append(
            "Time required to achieve the task: " + str((end - start).total_seconds()) + " seconds" + "\n")

        start_2 = datetime.now()

        time.sleep(4)

        end_2 = datetime.now()

        task2_info = "Second task"
        task2_title = '<center><h3><span style=\" color: #7eb346; font-weight:bold\">%s</span></h3></center>' % task2_info
        self.dlg.textBrowser.append(task2_title)
        self.dlg.textBrowser.append(
            "Time required to achieve the second task: " + str((end_2 - start_2).total_seconds()) + " seconds" + "\n")

class plugintestDialog: ## already created with qtDesigner

    What do I have to do here ?

    def start_busy(self):
        self.progressbar.setMaximum(0)

    def end_busy(self):
        self.progressbar.setMaximum(1)

class plugintest:

    messaging = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'plugintest_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.dlg = plugintestDialog()

        self.first_start = None

        self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buffering)


    def tr(self, message):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('plugintest', message)

    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        icon_path = ':/plugins/plugintest/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u''),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

        # will be set False in run()
        self.first_start = True

    def unload(self):
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&plugintest'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)


    def run(self):
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
        self.dlg.show()
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        if result:
            pass

    def start_busy(self):
        self.progressbar.setMaximum(0)

    def end_busy(self):
        self.progressbar.setMaximum(1)

    def run(self):
        self.dlg.show()
        result = self.dlg.exec_()

    def buffering(self):
        # disable pushbutton for avoid multi-clicks
        self.dlg.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        # start the busy state of the progressbar
        self.dlg.start_busy()
        # define the layer to process (just comment / uncomment what you want)
        self.layer = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()
        # self.layer  = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()
        # create a new task
        self.buffer_task = MyTask(self.layer)
        # connect the signals
        self.buffer_task.result.connect(self.add_map_layer)
        self.buffer_task.messaging.connect(lambda t: print(t))
        self.buffer_task.taskCompleted.connect(self.buffering_completed)
        # launch the processing of the task
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.buffer_task)

    def buffering_completed(self):
        self.dlg.end_busy()
        self.buffer_task.disconnect()
        self.dlg.pushButton.setEnabled(True)

    def add_map_layer(self, alg_output: dict):
        if alg_output['OUTPUT'].isValid:
            self.buffer = alg_output['OUTPUT']
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.buffer)


my_instance = plugintest(iface)
my_instance.run()
```

ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>plugintestDialogBase</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="plugintestDialogBase">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>389</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>plugintest</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="button_box">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>230</x>
     <y>350</y>
     <width>161</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="standardButtons">
    <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QgsMapLayerComboBox" name="mMapLayerComboBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>120</x>
     <y>30</y>
     <width>160</width>
     <height>27</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>180</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>47</width>
     <height>13</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Layer</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="textBrowser">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>80</x>
     <y>80</y>
     <width>256</width>
     <height>192</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>170</x>
     <y>290</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Run plugin</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>320</x>
     <y>300</y>
     <width>47</width>
     <height>13</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="pixmap">
    <pixmap resource="resources.qrc">:/plugins/plugintest/icon.png</pixmap>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QgsMapLayerComboBox</class>
   <extends>QComboBox</extends>
   <header>qgsmaplayercombobox.h</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources>
 </resources>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>button_box</sender>
   <signal>accepted()</signal>
   <receiver>plugintestDialogBase</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>button_box</sender>
   <signal>rejected()</signal>
   <receiver>plugintestDialogBase</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in my answer in the post you linked, I create a QgsTask `MyTask` with a layer parameter.

I just adapt the content of your method `buffering` in the `run` method of the QgsTask.

I defined 2 signals (`pyqtSignal`) in the QgsTask, one to send text (`messaging`) and the other to send a Python dict with the algorithm result (`result`).

A QgsTask `run` method must returns a boolean, `true` for success.

As I can't have access to your `plugintestDialog`, I created a minimal one with a PushButton and a [QProgressBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html).

I defined in the `plugintestDialog` 2 methods to start the busy status of the progressbar and end it.

I modified the method `buffering` to launch the task (see the comments in the code) and add 2 other methods and a lambda (can be an other method, just for the example to show a signal connected to a lambda function):

- `lambda t: print(t)` : when the QgsTask emits a messaging signal, this one is printed. You will do in your case something like : `lambda t: self.dlg.textBrowser.append(t)`
- `buffering_completed` : when the QgsTask is completed (buit-in signal `taskCompleted`), this method ends the busy status of the progressbar, disconnects all signals from the task instance and enables the pushbutton.
- `add_map_layer` : when the QgsTask has a result, it sends it through a dict and here, it contains the algorithm output, which is verified and added to the canvas if valid.

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *

from datetime import datetime
import os.path, os, shutil
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
import processing
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal



class MyTask(QgsTask):

    messaging = pyqtSignal(str)
    result = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, layer):
        super(MyTask, self).__init__()
        self.layer = layer

    def run(self):
        start = datetime.now()
        # buffer
        alg_params = {
            'DISSOLVE': True,
            'DISTANCE': 100,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
            'INPUT': self.layer,
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }

        buffer = processing.run('native:buffer', alg_params)
        self.result.emit(buffer)

        time.sleep(4)

        end = datetime.now()

        buffer_info = "Layer Buffering..."
        buffer_title = '<center><h3><span style=\" color: #7eb346; font-weight:bold\">%s</span></h3></center>' % buffer_info
        self.messaging.emit(buffer_title)
        self.messaging.emit("Time required to achieve the task: " + str((end - start).total_seconds()) + " seconds" + "\n")

        start_2 = datetime.now()

        time.sleep(4)

        end_2 = datetime.now()

        task2_info = "Second task"
        task2_title = '<center><h3><span style=\" color: #7eb346; font-weight:bold\">%s</span></h3></center>' % task2_info
        self.messaging.emit(task2_title)
        self.messaging.emit("Time required to achieve the second task: " + str((end_2 - start_2).total_seconds()) + " seconds" + "\n")

        return True


class plugintestDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(plugintestDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lyt = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Test 1", self)
        self.progressbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progressbar.setMinimum(0)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.progressbar)

    def start_busy(self):
        self.progressbar.setMaximum(0)

    def end_busy(self):
        self.progressbar.setMaximum(1)


class plugintest:

    messaging = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.dlg = plugintestDialog()
        self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buffering)

    def run(self):
        self.dlg.show()
        result = self.dlg.exec_()

    def buffering(self):
        # disable pushbutton for avoid multi-clicks
        self.dlg.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        # start the busy state of the progressbar
        self.dlg.start_busy()
        # define the layer to process (just comment / uncomment what you want)
        self.layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        # self.layer  = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()
        # create a new task
        self.buffer_task = MyTask(self.layer)
        # connect the signals
        self.buffer_task.result.connect(self.add_map_layer)
        self.buffer_task.messaging.connect(lambda t: print(t))
        self.buffer_task.taskCompleted.connect(self.buffering_completed)
        # launch the processing of the task
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.buffer_task)

    def buffering_completed(self):
        self.dlg.end_busy()
        self.buffer_task.disconnect()
        self.dlg.pushButton.setEnabled(True)

    def add_map_layer(self, alg_output: dict):
        if alg_output['OUTPUT'].isValid:
            self.buffer = alg_output['OUTPUT']
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.buffer)


my_instance = plugintest(iface)
my_instance.run()
```

Comment: First I thank you a lot for your reply Monticolo. Yet how can I add the `start_busy` and `end_busy` method to my `plugintestDialog` if I already created it with QtDesigner and called it with `.from .plugintest_dialog import plugintestDialog` ? I've edited my question based on your reply

Comment: sorry it worked I just had to replace ``self.dlg.start_busy()`` and ``self.dlg.end_busy()`` by ``self.dlg.progressBar.setMaximum(0)`` and ``self.dlg.progressBar.setMaximum(1)`` in the buffering method. I just can't make the textbrowser displayed the text but you helped me a lot already. thanks !

Comment: Everything works actually, thank you