# Conditional signals in QgsTask managing algorithm output

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, multithreading

Last question from my QgsTasks questions trilogy...

I'd like to insert a new processing algorithm with a raster as an input (let's say 'fill sinks' for instance) to the code provided by @Ben W in his reply [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/430368/164953).
My first thought is to define a new signal (like: `result2 = pyqtSignal(QgsRasterLayer)`) and manage something in the finished function with `self.result2.emit(self.result_DEM)` but my understanding of QgsTask and Python is not sufficient to make it work.

I swear it's my last request about that topic

(I don't want to make a a parent processing algorithm or full processing plugin since I have actually many other 'homemade' functions to insert to my code)

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *

from .resources import *
from .testplugin_dialog import testpluginDialog
from datetime import datetime
import os.path, os, shutil
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
import processing
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class MyTask(QgsTask):
    messaging = pyqtSignal(str)
    result = pyqtSignal(QgsVectorLayer)
    result2 = pyqtSignal(QgsRasterLayer)

    def __init__(self, desc, alg, params, task_no):
        self.desc = desc
        self.alg = alg
        self.params = params
        self.task_no = task_no
        self.result_layer = None
        self.result_DEM = None
        QgsTask.__init__(self, self.desc)

    def run(self):
        start = datetime.now()

        self.result_layer = processing.run(self.alg, self.params)['OUTPUT']
        self.result_DEM = processing.run(self.alg, self.params)['FILLED']

        end = datetime.now()

        self.messaging.emit(self.desc)
        self.messaging.emit(
            f"Time required to achieve task {self.task_no}: {str((end - start).total_seconds())} seconds\n")
        return True

    def finished(self, result, result2):
        if result:
            self.result.emit(self.result_layer)
        if result2:
            self.result2.emit(self.result_DEM)


class testpluginDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(testpluginDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lyt = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.cb = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self)
        self.cb2 = QgsMapLayerComboBox_2(self)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Test 1", self)
        self.progressbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progressbar.setMinimum(0)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.cb)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.progressbar)


class testplugin:

    messaging = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'testplugin_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.dlg = testpluginDialog()
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&testplugin')


        self.first_start = None

        self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.centroid)

    def tr(self, message):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('testplugin', message)

    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        icon_path = ':/plugins/testplugin/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u''),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

        # will be set False in run()
        self.first_start = True

    def unload(self):
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&testplugin'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)

    def run(self):
        self.dlg.show()
        result = self.dlg.exec_()

    def centroid(self):

        self.dlg.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.dlg.progressBar.setMaximum(0)
        layer = self.dlg.cb.currentLayer()

        centroid_params = {
            'ALL_PARTS': True,
            'INPUT': layer,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }

        # create task 1
        self.centroid_task = MyTask('Creating Centroids...', 'native:centroids', centroid_params, 1)
        # connect signals for task 1
        self.centroid_task.messaging.connect(lambda t: print(t))
        self.centroid_task.result.connect(lambda d: self.filled_sinks(d))
        # add task 1 to task manager
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.centroid_task)


    def filled_sinks(self, DEM):

        DEM = self.dlg.cb2.currentLayer()

        # Fill sinks (wang & liu)
        filled_sinks_params = {
            'ELEV': DEM,
            'MINSLOPE': 0.1,
            'FDIR': 'NULL',
            'FILLED': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
            'WSHED': 'NULL',
        }

        self.filled_sinks_task = MyTask('Creating filled DEM...', 'sagang:fillsinkswangliu', filled_sinks_params, 2)
        # connect signals for task 1
        self.filled_sinks_task.messaging.connect(lambda h: print(h))
        self.filled_sinks_task.result.connect(self.load_DEM)
        self.filled_sinks_task.result.connect(lambda l: self.buffering(l))
        # add task 1 to task manager
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.filled_sinks_task)


    def load_DEM(self, res_DEM):
        #Using .clone() seems to avoid unexpected behaviour exhibited when
        #loading the result layer directly into the projectd
        iface.addRasterLayer(res_DEM.clone(), 'DEM')



    def buffering(self, layer):
        buffer_params = {
        'DISSOLVE': True,
        'DISTANCE': 500,
        'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
        'INPUT': layer,
        'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
        'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
        'SEGMENTS': 5,
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        # create task 2
        self.buffer_task = MyTask('Creating Buffers...', 'native:buffer', buffer_params, 3)
        # connect signals for task 2
        self.buffer_task.messaging.connect(lambda t: print(t))
        self.buffer_task.result.connect(self.load_layer)
        self.buffer_task.taskCompleted.connect(self.buffering_completed)
        # add task 2 to task manager
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.buffer_task)

    def load_layer(self, res_lyr):
        #Using .clone() seems to avoid unexpected behaviour exhibited when
        #loading the result layer directly into the project
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(res_lyr.clone())

    def buffering_completed(self):
        self.dlg.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.dlg.progressBar.setMaximum(1)
        self.buffer_task.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the example below. Sorry, your code was a bit of a mess, I basically tried to make it functional in the quickest way that I could. I suggest to now study the code and do your own research and self learning so that you understand exactly what the code is actually doing. Most of Python plugin development really hinges around around PyQt, so I would suggest trying to build your knowledge in that area. Especially signal/ slot connections and catching objects emitted with signals.

I see you have posted your whole plugin code here. For my example below, to make testing easier for me, I have stuck with the simpler template from your previous question, so you will just need to adapt it into your plugin structure.

By the way, when I advocated in my last answer for using only one `QgsTask` subclass, I don't mean that you can't create more, it was just a suggestion for reducing redundancy based on the question you asked at the time. If your logic becomes more complicated with more tasks returning different result types, there is no reason why you can't create additional task subclasses.

Here is the working example:

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *

from datetime import datetime
import os.path, os, shutil
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
import processing
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal


class MyTask(QgsTask):
    messaging = pyqtSignal(str)
    vector_result = pyqtSignal(QgsVectorLayer)
    raster_result = pyqtSignal(str)
    

    def __init__(self, desc, alg, params, task_no):
        self.desc = desc
        self.alg = alg
        self.params = params
        self.task_no = task_no
        self.result_vector = None
        self.result_raster = None
        QgsTask.__init__(self, self.desc)
        

    def run(self):
        start = datetime.now()
        
        try:
            alg_result = processing.run(self.alg, self.params)
            if 'OUTPUT' in [k for k, v in alg_result.items()]:
                self.result_vector = alg_result['OUTPUT']
            if 'FILLED' in [k for k, v in alg_result.items()]:
                self.result_raster = alg_result['FILLED']
            end = datetime.now()
            self.messaging.emit(self.desc)
            self.messaging.emit(
                f"Time required to achieve task {self.task_no}: {str((end - start).total_seconds())} seconds\n")
            
        except QgsProcessingException:
            return False
        
        return True
        
    def finished(self, result):
        if result:
#            self.result_layer.moveToThread(QCoreApplication.instance().thread())
            if self.result_vector:
                self.vector_result.emit(self.result_vector)
            if self.result_raster:
                self.raster_result.emit(self.result_raster)
        else:
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage(f'Task {self.task_no} did not complete successfully')


class plugintestDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(plugintestDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lyt = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.cb = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self)
        self.cb2 = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Test 1", self)
        self.progressbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progressbar.setMinimum(0)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.cb)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.cb2)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.progressbar)


class plugintest:

    messaging = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.dlg = plugintestDialog()
        self.dlg.setMinimumWidth(350)
        self.dlg.cb.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.LineLayer | QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PolygonLayer)
        self.dlg.cb2.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.RasterLayer)
        self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.centroid)

    def run(self):
        self.dlg.show()
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        

    def centroid(self):
        self.dlg.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.dlg.progressbar.setMaximum(0)
        v_layer = self.dlg.cb.currentLayer()

        centroid_params = {
        'ALL_PARTS': True,
        'INPUT': v_layer,
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        
        # create centroid
        self.centroid_task = MyTask('Creating Centroids...', 'native:centroids', centroid_params, 1)
        # connect signals for task 1
        self.centroid_task.messaging.connect(lambda t: print(t))
        self.centroid_task.vector_result.connect(lambda d: self.buffering(d))
        # add task 1 to task manager
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.centroid_task)
        

    def buffering(self, layer):
        buffer_params = {
        'DISSOLVE': True,
        'DISTANCE': 100,
        'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
        'INPUT': layer,
        'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
        'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
        'SEGMENTS': 5,
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        # create task 2
        self.buffer_task = MyTask('Creating Buffers...', 'native:buffer', buffer_params, 2)
        # connect signals for task 2
        self.buffer_task.messaging.connect(lambda t: print(t))
        self.buffer_task.vector_result.connect(self.load_layer)
        self.buffer_task.taskCompleted.connect(self.fill_sinks)
        # add task 2 to task manager
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.buffer_task)
        
    def fill_sinks(self):
        r_layer = self.dlg.cb2.currentLayer()
        
        fill_sink_params = {
        'ELEV': r_layer,
        'MINSLOPE': 0.1,
        'FDIR': 'NULL',
        'FILLED': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
        'WSHED': 'NULL',
        }
        
        self.fill_sink_task = MyTask('Creating filled DEM...', 'sagang:fillsinkswangliu', fill_sink_params, 3)
        self.fill_sink_task.messaging.connect(lambda t: print(t))
        self.fill_sink_task.raster_result.connect(self.load_layer)
        self.fill_sink_task.taskCompleted.connect(self.tasks_completed)
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.fill_sink_task)

    def load_layer(self, res_lyr):
        if isinstance(res_lyr, QgsVectorLayer):
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(res_lyr.clone())
        if isinstance(res_lyr, str):
            iface.addRasterLayer(res_lyr, 'Filled DEM')

    def tasks_completed(self):
        self.dlg.progressbar.setMaximum(1)
#        self.buffer_task.disconnect()
        self.dlg.pushButton.setEnabled(True)


my_instance = plugintest(iface)
my_instance.run()
```

See test working in screencast below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help... and yes I will soon look for a PyQt MOOC to understand all of that more precisely

Comment: @Linda, you're welcome. Even some free video series on YouTube are a good starting point. Knowledge of Qt is a huge advantage for any QGIS development! Good luck :-)