# Accessing layers from QgsContext transferred by completed QgsTask using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, qgis-processing, standalone, parallel-processing

We have a headless QGIS standalone script that needs to run some I/O intensive layer retrieval tasks, each as parallel background threads before doing further GIS processing.

We are invoking our custom task as follows, but are unclear how to fetch the resulting layers from each of the completed tasks.

```py
import processing
from qgis.core import *

ctx = QgsProcessingContext()
mgr = QgsTaskManager()
mgr.addTask(CustomTask(ctx, params1))
mgr.addTask(CustomTask(ctx, params2))
all(task.waitForFinished(timeout=0) for task in mgr.tasks())

# PROBLEM: how to retrieve task's map layer?
ctx.getMapLayer(<lyr_id>) # requires unknown layer id at caller
ctx.temporaryLayerStore().mapLayers()  # gives empty dict!
```

.. & our simplified custom task based off this [manual](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html#extending-qgstask) & [blog](https://www.opengis.ch/2018/06/22/threads-in-pyqgis3/) example looks something like this:

```py
class CustomTask(QgsTask):
  def __init__(self, ctx: QgsProcessingContext, params: dict):
    super().__init__()
    self._params = params
    self._lyr = None
    self._ctx = ctx

  def run(self) -> bool:
    # assume this is a more complex sequence of expensive logic
    # like a user-defined Callable[..., QgsMapLayer] function 
    # passed in the task's constructor.
    self._lyr = processing.run("qgis:executesql", self._params).get('OUTPUT')
    return True

  def finished(self, run_result: bool):
    if run_result:
       # transfer ownership between worker/caller threads via 
       # passed in context before task is garbage collected.
       self._ctx.temporaryLayerStore().addMapLayer(
          self._ctx.takeResultLayer(self._lyr.id())
       )
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CodeBard's hints, the trick was to manually transfer layer ownership & add it to the caller's context within the task's `run()` method. Also, the task manager call site needed to explicitly wait for proper task finishing & cleanup by passing a `timeout=-1`.

Our general solution is as follows, which behaves similarly to `QgsTask.fromFunction()` but returns results in a context. Particularly useful when the GIS logic does not rely on `processing.run()` to populate the context.

```py
from typing import Callable, Optional
from qgis.core import QgsTask, QgsMapLayer
from functools import partial

class CustomTask(QgsTask):

    # run custom function in background thread & store results in context.
    def __init__(self, ctx: QgsProcessingContext, fn: Callable[..., QgsMapLayer], *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(description=fn.__name__)
        self._fn = partial(fn, *args, **kwargs)
        self._ctx = ctx
        self._exception: Optional[Exception] = None

    # transfer worker/caller threads ownership before garbage collection.
    def run(self) -> bool:
        try:
            lyr = self._fn()
            lyr.moveToThread(self._ctx.thread())
            self._ctx.temporaryLayerStore().addMapLayer(lyr)
            return True
        except Exception as ex:
            self._exception = ex
            return False

    # propagate any exceptions to the caller thread.
    def finished(self, run_result: bool):
        if not run_result:
            raise self._exception
        return
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `QgsProcessingContext` is supposed to store the result of the processing algorithm, you will need to pass the context as argument to
`processing.run(..)`.

In addition it requires setting the parameter `is_child_algorithm` to `True`. If `is_child_algorithm` is `False` (by default) the context does not store the result layer in its temporary layer store but rather transfers ownership immediately back to caller.

The following code is an example that can be pasted in the console.

```
import processing
from qgis.core import *


class CustomTask(QgsTask):
    def __init__(self, ctx: QgsProcessingContext, params: dict):
        super().__init__()
        self._params = params
        self._lyr_id = None
        self._ctx = ctx

    def run(self) -> bool:
        self._lyr_id = processing.run(
            "qgis:randompointsinextent", 
            self._params, 
            context=self._ctx, # pass context to processing!
            is_child_algorithm=True,
            ).get('OUTPUT', None)
        return self._lyr_id is not None

    def finished(self, run_result: bool):
        if run_result:
            # nothing else to do here, context is already owner of the layers
            print('success!')
        return


ctx = QgsProcessingContext()
mgr = QgsTaskManager()

params = {
    'EXTENT': '4.63,11.57,44.41,48.78 [EPSG:4326]',
    'MIN_DISTANCE': 0.1,
    'POINTS_NUMBER': 100,
    'TARGET_CRS': 'EPSG:4326',
    'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
}
mgr.addTask(CustomTask(ctx, params))
mgr.addTask(CustomTask(ctx, params))
all(task.waitForFinished() for task in mgr.tasks())

print(ctx.temporaryLayerStore().mapLayers()) # now returns dict of two layers from the two tasks

# for display purposes, to confirm successful results
for l_id, layer in ctx.temporaryLayerStore().mapLayers().items():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Comment: +1 for the transfer vs store context insight.  Approach seems similar to subclassing `QgsProcessingAlgorithm`. Would you know how to **manually** populate the caller’s context with the produced layer if our task does not actually call any `processing.run()` algos but does something customized instead?

Comment: I am not completely certain but you could possibly call `self._ctx.temporaryLayerStore().addMapLayer(layer)` in the `run` function to populate a layer manually.

Comment: Also if you are not using any processing algorithm in the task at all, you might have more success in using a signal to send results back to main thread (e.g. discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/430368/187445)) instead of using Qgs**Processing**Context which is clearly meant for usage in processing algorithms :)

Comment: Do you know if those pieces of vital knowledge are documented somewhere officially? Or did you find out by reading source code?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I don't think it's documented anywhere. For most of the more intricate pyqgis applications there is often no choice but to try to find something suitable in the source code. I mostly find relevant information in the C++ API docs which sometimes give some more insights than the pyqgis one and provide a direct link to the source code for each function.